# Running Dask in a Singularity Container

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, singularity-container

I have been trying to go through the tutorial of Dask on an HPC environment as given on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXsgmwpRExM.

I have managed to install all the packages I need in a Singularity image and am then running the image on a LSF cluster using: `bsub -ISs -q "par-multi" -J "ipy_test" -n 16 singularity shell container.img`

After, I start ipython using the simple `ipython` command and then import LSFCluster from dask_jobqueue using `from dask_jobqueue import LSFCluster`

Then, I set up my test cluster by calling `cluster = LSFCluster(cores=2, memory="1 GB")` and set off 2 workers by calling `cluster.scale(2)` at which point I get the following stack trace:

> tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in
>   _run_callback
>       ret = callback()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line
>   300, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py", line 416, in
>   scale_up
>       self.start_workers(n - self._count_active_and_pending_workers())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py", line
>   330, in start_workers
>       out = self._submit_job(fn)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/lsf.py", line 114, in
>   _submit_job
>       return self._call(piped_cmd, shell=True)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask_jobqueue/core.py", line 383, in
>   _call
>       cmd_str, out, err)) RuntimeError: Command exited with non-zero exit code. Exit code: 127 Command: bsub < /tmp/tmpipG68P.sh 2>
>   /dev/null stdout: stderr:

Would anyone have an idea of where I might be going awry?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pulling a pre-built Dask Docker container into Singularity instead? It could be that your build has conflicting installs. See: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/docker.html